# Мусор в конце чтения fread при отладке

Tags: файлы, mingw

Следующим образом читаю весь файл:

```
    FILE * f = fopen(path,"r");
long fsize;
char* buffer;
  if (f!=NULL)
  {
    fseek(f, 0L, SEEK_END);
    fsize = ftell(f);
    rewind( f );
    buffer = new char[fsize];

    fread(buffer,fsize,1,f);

    fclose (f);
  }
```

Компилирую через GNU 4.8.1 на Windows x64
При прямом выполнении программы все нормально, но во время отладки через GNU gdb после записи в buffer получаю содержимое файла в мусором в пару десятков байт в конце, хотя fsize во всех случаях верный, то есть под buffer выделяется одинаковое количество памяти. Как исправить?

Comment: Файл записан в текстовом виде или бинарном?

Comment: Открывайте файл, как бинарный (`fopen(path, "rb");`)

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow, в текстовом

Comment: @avp, тот же результат

Answer (score 4, accepted):

buffer = new char **[fsize + 1]**; //Данные из файла + завершающий '\0'.

fread(buffer,fsize,1,f);

**buffer[fsize] = 0;** // Принудительный нуль-символ для С-строки.

Comment: спасибо, значит принудительно нужно указать конец строки)) Только странно то, что такое поведение наблюдается только если запускать через GNU отладчик

Comment: Отладка в дебаге может отличаться поведением от релизной и у разных компиляторов, конечно, тоже.

Comment: ок, только еще один момент. При использовании табуляций или переноса строки в файле для чтения получаю тот же эффект - только при отладке немного мусора добавляется

Comment: хотя, эта проблема решается вторым аргументом `rb` в fopen

Comment: "Управляющие символы" могут иметь разное представление и формат хранения в файле. Видимо, поэтому.